# Orbeon Forms - how to make read-only fields

Tags: forms, orbeon

So i have this orbeon form and I would like to make some fields as read-only. I'am wondering what kind of expression should I use in the box dedicated to Read-Only feature. Attached image shows which part I would like to have read only.

[Orbeon Form - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trtrB.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First you have old version of Orbeon. Try think about updating to new version.

Second, write some Xpath expression to that field. Result will be evaluated to true or false. If you want only set Read-Only use `true()` expression. Next example can be `$control(1) = 'Hello'`.

Comment: `true()` is correct. With newer versions of Orbeon Forms, you can directly choose a radio button to indicate that the field is always readonly. Your second expression above is not valid XPath, though. Try just `$control-1` for a control called `control-1`.